# Pass checkbox values 1 if checked if not 0to PHP using AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, checkbox

I would like to insert the "0" or "1" into mysql database by using php checkbox but values could not be stored into database !
i'trying to insert an array of checkbox like this :

1: selected

0: not selected

```
[answer] => Array
        (
            [0] => answer 1
            [1] => answer  2
            [2] => answer  3
        )

[check] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1
        )
```

php file :

```
<td> <!-- <input type="hidden"  name="check[]" value="0" >-->
     <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check[]" value="1">
</td>
```

in the process file via AJAX i store the answer database but i could not store the checked value for each annswer selected

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO questions 
                         (nom_question,id_categorie)       
                     VALUES('$question','$categorie')", $conn) 
                     or die(mysql_error());

//last insert id question
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();

$check =  $_POST['check']; 

foreach ($reponse as $key=>$value  ) {
    $values = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $x='1';
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO reponses 
                         (nom_reponse,id_question,id_categorie,correct) 
                         VALUES ('$values',
                                 '$last_id',
                                 '$categorie',
                                 '$x')") 
                or die(mysql_error());
```

plz help ! how could i store answer with check if checked or not  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks a lot sir for replay; but the problem is the checkbox is dynamique and the selected value depends on the users !! 
and i have used form serliaze to send pot data via ajax : the checkbox are in the form

```
<form name="form" id="form" role="form" method="post" action="">
<<tr>
                        <td>Answer</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="name" name="answer[]"></td>

                        <td>

                                <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check[]" ></td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="Ajouter" " class="button"></td>
                    </tr>
</form>
```

how could i choose the selected answer ! the idea is too store one if the answer is true if not store 0 in the colum 'correct' in database

i try by this way process data by AJAX

```
 $(function() {
                $("#form").on("submit", function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "test.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function(d) {
                            alert(d);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple really, you have to remember that CheckBoxes only get sent to the script from the html form, **IF** they are actually checked, so unchecked checkboxes just dont exist in the $_POST or $_GET array.

This is not as big a problem as it seems, all you need to do is check for the existance of a checkbox and if it exists then it was checked.

So in your code rather than doing this

```
$check =  $_POST['check'];
```

Do this

```
$check =  isset($_POST['check']) ? 1 : 0;
```

I would go further and show the code to store it in the database but your code does not actually use the `$check` variable anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

try this for post with ajax
change id to class to easy selecting

```
var selectedCB = new Array();
$('.cbcheck:checked').each(function() {
            selectedCB.push(this.value);
          });
          $.ajax({
            url: 'insert.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            data: {recordsval: selectedCB},
            success: function( data){
              $('#result').html(data);
            },
            error: function(errorThrown ){
              console.log( errorThrown );
            }
          });


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="cbcheck" name="check[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="cbcheck" name="check[]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="cbcheck" name="check[]" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
<div id="result"></div>
```

and php handle

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['recordsval'];
var_dump($data);
?>
```

adapt this with your code...